# Laravel how to create empty relationship?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a condition inside a relationship where if the user is logged in it will return the relation and if not i want it to return empty relationship.
here is what i want :

```
public function dummy()
{
    return (auth()->user()) ? $this->hasOne(blah::class) : emptyrelationship();
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to return from this empty relationship?

Comment: ^ prettified null probably :D

Comment: What do you mean with "prettified null"

Comment: what is prettified null ? and null throw exceptions with eager loading

Answer (score 1):

To return an empty relationship instead of null, you can try this:

```
public function item()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Item::class)
        ->withDefault(function () {
            return new Item();
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check with DD() what is being returned as you like.

If there's no data for the relationship to show, it will just return no data.

Comment: i don't understand what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try This example

```
public function shop(){
    if(true) {
        return $this->newQuery(); // or newQueryWithoutScopes()
    }
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Shop');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no user in the user table collection will return relationship as "relationship: user: []" as blank only  if you do dd($var) on your query,then you can check though conditions in your code;

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent has a method for that [newModelInstance](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_newModelInstance)

Best to keep the eloquent model standard relationship and move logic elsewhere

```
public function dummy()
{
    return $this->hasOne(blah::class);
}

$dummy = $model->dummy;
if (!$dummy) {
    $dummy = $model->dummy()->newModelInstance();
}
```